# Change the state of an array of checkboxes on the reducer as it changes in the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have something like this on React:

```
const CheckboxItems = (t) => [ // that t is just a global prop
  {
    checked: true,
    value: 'itemsCancelled',
    id: 'checkBoxItemsCancelled',
    labelText: t('cancellations.checkBoxItemsCancelled'),
  },
  {
    checked: true,
    value: 'requestDate',
    id: 'checkboxRequestDate',
    labelText: t('cancellations.checkboxRequestDate'),
  },
  {
    checked: true,
    value: 'status',
    id: 'checkboxStatus',
    labelText: t('cancellations.checkboxStatus'),
  },
  {
    checked: true,
    value: 'requestedBy',
    id: 'checkboxRequestedBy',
    labelText: t('cancellations.checkboxRequestedBy'),
  },
];

class TableToolbarComp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: CheckboxItems(),
  };

  onChange = (value, id, event) => {
    const { columnsFilterHandler } = this.props;
    this.setState(({ items }) => {
      const item = items.slice().find(i => i.id === id);
      if (item) {
        item.checked = !item.checked;
        columnsFilterHandler(id, item.value, item.checked);
        return { items };
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return(
      <>
             {items.map(item => (
                <ToolbarOption key={item.id}>
                  <Checkbox
                    id={item.id}
                    labelText={item.labelText}
                    value={item.value}
                    checked={item.checked}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                  />
                </ToolbarOption>
              ))}
      </>
    )
  }

export default compose(
  connect(
    ({ cancellations }) => ({
      columnId: cancellations.columnId,
      columnValue: cancellations.columnValue,
      isChecked: cancellations.isChecked,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      columnsFilterHandler: (columnId, columnValue, isChecked) => {
        dispatch(columnsFilterAction(columnId, columnValue, isChecked));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(translate()(TableToolbarComp));
```

That works very well and it is dispatching the data I would need to use later.

But I have a mess on the Redux part which is changing the state of all of the checkboxes at once and not separately as it should. So, once I uncheck one of the checkboxes the other 3 also get `checked: false`. I don't see this change to `checked: false` on the UI, only I see it on the Redux console in the browser.

This is what I have in the reducer

```
const initialState = {
  checkboxes: [
    {
      checked: true,
      value: 'itemsCancelled',
      id: 'checkBoxItemsCancelled',
    },
    {
      checked: true,
      value: 'requestDate',
      id: 'checkboxRequestDate',
    },
    {
      checked: true,
      value: 'status',
      id: 'checkboxStatus',
    },
    {
      checked: true,
      value: 'requestedBy',
      id: 'checkboxRequestedBy',
    },
  ],
}

[ActionTypes.COLUMNS_FILTER](state, action) {
    return initialState.checkboxes.map(checkbox => {
      if (!checkbox.id === action.payload.id) {
        return checkbox;
      }
      return {
        ...checkbox,
        checked: action.payload.isChecked,
      };
    });
 }
```

Action:

```
const columnsFilterAction = (columnId, columnValue, isChecked) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.COLUMNS_FILTER,
  payload: { columnId, columnValue, isChecked },
});
```

So all I need to know is what I have to do manage the state of those checkboxes on Redux as it working on React. As all I see is that when I toggle the checkboxes all of them reach the same state.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is pass the `id` of the checkbox you want to toggle in an action. That's all you need in an action to toggle state. Then in the reducer you want to map over the current state and just return the checkbox for any that don't match the `id` passed in the action. When the `id` does match, return a new option spreading the current checkbox's properties into the new object and setting the `checked` property to it's opposite.

Given this action:

```
const TOGGLE_CHECKBOX = 'TOGGLE_CHECKBOX'
function toggleCheckbox(id) {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_CHECKBOX,
    id
  }
}
```

[Actions - Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions) - Guide to actions and action creators provided by the author of Redux.

This reducer will do the job.

```
function checkboxReducer(state = [], action = {}) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_CHECKBOX:
      return state.map(checkbox => {
        if (checkbox.id !== action.id) {
          return checkbox;
        }
        return {
          ...checkbox,
          checked: checkbox.isChecked ? false : true,
        }
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

[Reducers - Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) - Guide to reducers and how to handle actions provided by the author of Redux.

Here is a working [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrm2mvnqmx) to demonstrate it working. You can click the checkboxes to see them toggling as expected.

Comment: I am getting this error -> `Uncaught TypeError: state.map is not a function`

Comment: Make sure you set the default shape of your state to an array. `(state = [], action = {})`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get that part. If you see my code, I have an initialState object at the top of my reducer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @TheUnnamed I made a code sandbox for you to look at so that you can see it in action. I added it to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Ok I saw the code sandbox link already but I am having issues trying to adapt your solution to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have `!checkbox.id === action.payload.id` as your condition logic. As all of your checkbox IDs are 'truthy', then this !checkbox.id evaluates to false, and is the same as writing `if(false === action.payload.id)`.

I suspect you meant to write: `if(checkbox.id !== action.payload.id)`.

Comment: I already change that but I am still not getting what I need. Are you sure that's all wrong with my code?